# MS Access Table Named Macro – Identifier could not found?

Tags: ms-access, macros

I was trying to edit a database using MS access macro and an error pops up saying:

> The identifier '[OldPriceCodePass]' could not be found.

Please see the snapshot of the codes. I am just a beginner in using Access and not a computer programmer. Please help...

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/cf7988ad-da77-4741-83b8-8b4fa32c4ed3/data-macro-error-the-identifier-could-not-be-found-error-number-2950?forum=accessdev or https://access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=216674 ?

Answer (score 0):

You should explicitly state the collection the variable is in:

`ReturnVars!OldPriceCodePass` instead of just `OldPriceCodePass`